# MCRYPT functions returning wrong results

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I'm trying to encode and decode some random strings I've made using MCRYPT but they don't decode properly.

Here's the function I'm using to encode the strings:

```
function m_encrypt($key, $text, $iv) {
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
}
```

As you can see it takes a pre-defined "key" I've written, the text to encode and the iv which is created in a seperate file. It then encrypts the data and returns it.

Here's the function which inserts the string into the database:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO randomStrings(random_string, iv) VALUES (:random_string, :iv)');
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

$rows = 50;

for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $randString = get_random_string($chars, 20);
    $randString = m_encrypt($key, $randString, $iv);
    $sth->bindParam(':random_string', $randString);
    $sth->bindParam(':iv', $iv);
    $sth->execute();    
}
```

I merely insert the string and iv into the database.

Next I try to read the encoded string using this:

```
function m_decrypt($key, $text, $iv) {
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
}
```

Similar to the encode function, but the opposite.

Finally, the file which tries to decrypt the string looks like this:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM randomStrings');
$sth->execute();    

while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo m_decrypt($key, $result['random_string'], $result['iv']);
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

The result is always some arbitrary set of characters like

```
í,eHGxC•z»@”“§``
```

I know this cannot be right as I have limited the characters to be used in the random string generation to simple a-z and 0-9 so this can't possibly be the correct decoding, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stupid question: are you using the same `$key` in the decrypt script?

Comment: @GordonFreeman Yes, the $key is in one file which all others include.

Comment: Have you verified that what goes into the database also comes out of it, binary, unmodified, even if it contains null characters?

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger No I haven't, how would I try doing that? Also, by looking through the table I can see a lot of whitespace in both the string and iv columns do you think this could be a problem? I'm storing the data as Varchar, is there something better I could be using?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the encrypted string and/or the IV is mangled by your database.  To test whether this is the case, you can just save them in the database, fetch them back immediately and compare the results with the originals.

You haven't specified which database software you're using, but if it's MySQL, the appropriate column type for storing encrypted data is either [`VARBINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-varbinary.html) or [`BLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html).  (For IVs, which should have a constant length, `BINARY` can work too.  Actually, though, the *usual* way of storing IVs is to simply prepend them to the encrypted string.)